# Add element to array without overwriting it in php?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm trying to add a new element to an array from form values in php.  However every time I do this I overwrite the most recent element.  So my existing array is like this:

```
$moviepages = [[ "title" => "test1",
"description" => "this is my test"

]
];
```

And I want to add this (created through form values) to it:

```
$newfile = [

  "title" => "test2",
"description" => "test2",

 ];
```

by doing this:

```
    $moviepages[] = $newfile;
```

However I need to add elements continuously so that when different users come in they can add items on to the same array without the previous array element getting removed. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: That should work just fine. Can you post the whole code you are using?

Comment: Your code should work..

Comment: It does work it just overwrites the last element.  So say one user goes in and sends the below values:   $newfile = [
     
          "title" => $_POST['title'],
        "image" => $dstFile,
    "description" => $_POST['description'],
    "mood" => $_POST['mood']
      ];   Everytime a new form is submitted essentially a new array is created, and the previous users values are removed rather than it being updated.

Comment: You're talking about different users? For that you should store the array in a database. Add the new elements and if you want to list all of them you should do a SELECT to show all the elements.

Comment: For this particular project I can't- would it be easier to do it through file_put_contents- and try to specify where to add the new array in (although I don't know how to do that)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your form values are stored in an array you can try to use `array_merge()` to merge the two arrays together. For example;

```
array_merge($moviepages, $newFile)
```

**EDIT**

You can also try the array_merge_recursive() function as it does not delete the previous entries but just creates a new array for those values. For example;

This code;

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green");
$a2=array("c"=>"blue","b"=>"yellow");
print_r(array_merge_recursive($a1,$a2));
```

will produce this result;

```
Array ( [a] => red [b] => Array ( [0] => green [1] => yellow ) [c] => blue )
```

This explanation is from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge_recursive.asp) for the difference between the two.

> The difference between this function(array_merge_recursive()) and the array_merge() function is
>   when two or more array elements have the same key. Instead of override
>   the keys, the array_merge_recursive() function makes the value as an
>   array.

As for file_put_contents-, try to check out [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_put_contents.asp) and [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_function_file_put_contents.htm)

Let me know if it works for you or if you have any problem.

Comment: It still just over writes it- would it be easier to do it through file_put_contents- and try to specify where to add the new array in (although I don't know how to do that)?  Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer so you can take a look at it. As for file_put_contents-, i can only reference you to some tutorials.